# three.js positioning mesh cubes not working for different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I noticed different screen sizes cause incorrect positioning of objects.

Best example of this is using this page:

http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_voxelpainter

On larger laptop screen the cubes are positioned correctly, when viewing the same page on a smaller smartphone screen blocks are positioned in consistently incorrect positions.

Click in the bottom right corner of the grid and the blocks get positioned in the center

Answer (score 0):

That's because your screen is in zoom mode. Try using ctrl+0 (cmd+0 in mac) to revert it back. Interactive functionalities in three.js in some points have problems when you are in zoom mode.

Comment: The issue is on the HTC one mini.  When i click in the bottom right corner the blocks are shown in the middle left. I have tried changing the browser window view size but get the same results. Here is an image of the issue https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6249